# How to select everything but a certain html element using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Example:

```
import bs4

html = '''
<div class="short-description std ">
<em>Android Apps Security</em> provides guiding principles for how to 
best design and develop Android apps with security in mind. The book explores 
techniques that developers can use to build additional layers of security into 
their apps beyond the security controls provided by Android itself.             
<p class="scroll-down">∨ <a href="#main-desc" onclick="Effect.ScrollTo(
'main-desc', { duration:'0.2'}); return false;">Full Description</a> ∨</p></div>
'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

How do I get the following(a beautifulsoup object) from `soup`?

```
<div class="short-description std ">
<em>Android Apps Security</em> provides guiding principles for how to 
best design and develop Android apps with security in mind. The book explores 
techniques that developers can use to build additional layers of security into 
their apps beyond the security controls provided by Android itself.             
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply search for it:

```
soup.find('p', class_='scroll-down')
```

I used the class to limit the find, but since there are no other `p` elements that's a little redundant here.

If, instead, you need to remove the tag, use the above method to first find it, then call [`.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) on it to remove it from the document:

```
>>> soup.find('p', class_='scroll-down').extract()
<p class="scroll-down"> <a href="#main-desc" onclick="Effect.ScrollTo(
'main-desc', { duration:'0.2'}); return false;">Full Description</a> </p>
>>> print soup

<div class="short-description std ">
<em>Android Apps Security</em> provides guiding principles for how to 
best design and develop Android apps with security in mind. The book explores 
techniques that developers can use to build additional layers of security into 
their apps beyond the security controls provided by Android itself.             
</div>
```

Two things: the removed tag is returned from the `.extract()` method, you could save it for later use. The tag is removed from the document altogether, you'd have to re-add it manually later if you still need it to be in the document anyway.

Alternatively, you could use the [`.decompose()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose), which deletes the tag from the document altogether, without returning a reference. The tag is then gone forever.

Comment: I'm sorry Martijn, the question in the title was correct but I missphrased the question in the example. I edited it, it should've been **everything but the `p` element** instead of **the `p` element**. Your answer just gets the `p` element.

Comment: @Bentley4: the question is still ambiguous as to what you expect the output to be and what you want to do with the remainder. Your question also is still incorrect, to filter *out* everything but the `p` element is to only select the `p` element. I suspect you want it the other way around.

Comment: I used *filter out* as a synonym for *select*. So what I want is to select everything but the `p` element. I changed filter out to select in the question.

Comment: You haven't yet stated what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to print out the HTML minus the `p` tag, do you need extract the text, do you need to search for other tags that are *not* contained in the `p` tag, etc. Each use has a different approach to follow.

Comment: And to filter *out* is to remove something from the whole, to remove it. Filter out the sediment from drinking water, etc. To filter *for* is to select, by removing everything you don't want. :-)

Comment: I re-edited the original question again. According to your explanation what I meant is **the remainder from the process of filtering out the element `p`** from `soup`. I didn't know this terminology to that level of detail, sorry.

Comment: I'll ask differently: *Why* do you want to get the rest of the tags minus the `p` tag? What are you trying to *do* with the result?

Comment: I'm going to do `.get_text()` on the remainder. The content of the `p` element is variable in the real case.

Comment: @Bentley4: I gave you one method that removes tags from the document altogether. It'll work fine for using `.get_text()` on it, but do note that it alters the document.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! Btw I already found an ugly way of getting what I wanted by using the `contents` attribute after converting the `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` to a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` object. But your clean solution is what I was looking for.